# How do I stop IE11 offering to save passwords on edit pages that are not login forms?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, autocomplete, passwords, internet-explorer-11

Part of our application allows the user to edit entities that have passwords. It does not make sense for them to save these passwords; as they would never log in as these types of users directly.

It's a bit of an annoyance than when you edit one of these entities, IE11 "helpfully" asks if you want to remember the password.

Seemingly IE11 ignores `<form autocomplete="off">` on the form; and still asks `Would you like to store your password for (hostname)?`.

How can we disable this? We don't mind it on the login page; but it doesn't make sense here, it's just an annoyance. (Note: Having the user click `Not for this site` is not a good solution; as it will also stop it working from the login page).

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the IEInternals discussion on [this very topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/10/troubleshooting-stored-login-problems-in-ie.aspx)?  (I'm not certain, but I think the part you're interested in appears later in the post.  I do recommend working through the various links, though, as there appear to be several different factors in play.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: This isn't really an answer?

Comment: Given the details you've provided and the complexity of the issues identified in the article I linked to, it seems like there isn't enough information on the table to identify a specific answer.  I would start by going through the article to get a sense of the various factors and then compare those to your implementation.  Hopefully, that will lead you to the next question and possibly even your specific answer.